# DNS Server for windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have a server for my web sites ( windows 2003 standard ).
I have about 20 web sites host on this. 
my most important problem is DNS server , I use windows DNS Server , but some of sites and in some times , have DNS probelm , can't be found , 
Also my monitoring service report DNS problem and the score that set for DNS was 0 from 10.

How Can I speed up my DNS server? (any soltion or other DNS server suggestion)

Edit:
Thaks for your response and suggestions. But I want to know how can I optimize my DNS server setting , in Event log I find many warning by Evend Id 7062 or 3000 , I need to know more , its low speed ralated to my setting , or Windows DNS is not a good solution. Is BIND better than windows DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not very experienced in how to run a DNS server and outsourcing is an option, you could let your domain or hosting provider do that for you. Normally their infrastructure is better and you don't have to care about that kind of problems.

Almost all service providers offer this as free (included) service and allow you to use a web interface for adding changing the DNS settings of your domains.

Comment: Agreed.  One server with DNS is not enough.  A single Windows DNS is not a good enough solution for what is trying to be done here.  Outsourcing this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one DNS server, your should add one more secondary DNS servers to serve your domains, at least it is what related RFC states. It should be preferably located somewhere else, not where your servers are now.

What I recommend though is going with some DNS only service provider, like [DNSMadeEasy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/u/43729)
This way you can reach almost 100% DNS uptime. It is  not a guarantee, it just what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit of pushing DNS hosting to your ISP or another provider is you'll save some bandwidth/processing power as people won't have to hit your servers when resolving domain data.

I used to host DNS internally and then realised it just wasn't cost effective maintaining two name servers when most ISP's provide the service free.  If you need more control you can use a company like SafeDNS.co.uk or a free provider like zoneedit (free for the first 5 domains).